# How to display all icons from icons folder in vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, validation, import

Created a small project with vuejs and want to display all my icons but for some reason it does not displays my icons, Can anyone tell me where I am making the mistakes.
I want to display all my icons from that icons list in the div element.
Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

ValidatingProps.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>How to use Validation in props</h1>
    <h3>{{ status }}</h3>
    <div class="icons" v-html="icons"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import icons from "./icons";

console.log(icons);

export default {
  name: "validatingProps",
  props: {
    status: {
      type: String,
      default: "Validating",
      validator: (value) => {
        console.log("Val", value);
        return ["in-progress", "complete"].includes(value);
      },
    },
    icons: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      validator: (value) => {
        console.log("Value >>>> ", value);
        Object.keys(icons).includes(value);
        console.log("Icons props: ", Object.keys(icons).includes(value));
      },
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("mounted ", Object.keys(icons));
    console.log("this.Icons: ", this.icons);
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.icons {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: lightcyan;
}
```

App.vue

```
<div>
<template>
  <ValidatingProps
      status="progress"
      :icons="Object.keys(this.icons.default)"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ValidatingProps from "./components/validatingProps.vue";
import * as icon from "./components/icons/";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    ValidatingProps,
  },

 data() {
    return {
      icons: icon,
   }
}
</script>
```

my icons folder structure:

[image]

My Div box shows:

[image]

Comment: what exactly do your "icon" files contain?  I see after importing you have an array of strings.  how do you anticipate these strings be converted to an icon image? do you have some icon library or actual icon images anywhere?

Comment: yes each the icon file contains SVG code like `<svg viewBox="0 0 17 17" fill="none"><path d="M8.4192..... </svg>`;